# i want to know Whether user rated my app already or not in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

is it possible to know this in flutter ?

Comment: It is not possible. Not in flutter, not in native nowhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that
this is against google policy because you may reward users if they rated your app but you can ask users to rate the app after using it a couple of time
this package will help you to do that [rate my app flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/rate_my_app)

Comment: using plugin's will always show the alert box to user after all the conditions are satisfied , but if the user already rated the app it will irritate them .

Comment: the plugin will ask users to rate the app if they deleted the app from the device and reinstall it. Unfortunately, You cannot check if users really rated the app or not this is against google policy.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to know if user already rated app, but it is possible and recommended not to annoy user with the same dialog again and again.

When the rating condition is met, you can show a dialog like this:

[image]

If the user hits `Yes` or `Already rated`, you will set a boolean variable `alreadyRated`, to `true`, persist it and will never show dialog again. If user pressed `Remind me later` you will wait several days before showing it again.